# Connecting to postgresql from a groovy script executed at command line

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to run a groovy script which loads data into a Postgresql database. It runs perfectly using IntelliJ but fails when run from the windows command line with the following error:

```
 Caught: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at UploadStressTestData.run(UploadStressTestData.groovy:118)
```

Apparently, the groovy script can't find the driver class. I need to somehow make that available or loadable from that script.

My question is, how do I do that? Do I need to use the -cp option and tell it where the postgresql driver is?

Any help vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

groovy -cp C:\Users\someuser\workspace\lib\postgresql-42.2.6.jre7.jar  UploadStressTestData.groovy

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case you should be using [@Grab](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Grab.html) to pull dependencies for your scripts:

```
@Grab('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.6')

// do your scripting stuff
```